# Optimizing file parse and SNS publish of large record set

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, aws-lambda, amazon-sns

I have an 85mb data file with 110k text records in it. I need to parse each of these records, and publish an SNS message to a topic for each record. I am doing this successfully, but the Lambda function requires a lot of time to run, as well as a large amount of memory. Consider the following:

```
const parse = async (key) => {

    //get the 85mb file from S3. this takes 3 seconds
    //I could probably do this via a stream to cut down on memory...
    let file = await getFile( key );

    //parse the data by new line
    const rows = file.split("\n");

    //free some memory now
    //this free'd up ~300mb of memory in my tests
    file = null;

    //
    for( let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++ ) {

        //... parse the row and build a small JS object from it

        //publish to SNS. assume publishMsg returns a promise after a successful SNS push
        requests.push( publishMsg(data) );
    }


    //wait for all to finish
    await Promise.all(requests);
    return 1;

};
```

The Lambda function will timeout with this code at 90 seconds (the current limit I have set). I could raise this limit, as well as the memory (currently at 1024mb) and likely solve my issue. But, none of the SNS publish calls take place when the function hits the timeout. Why?

Lets say 10k rows process before the function hits the timeout. Since I am submitting the publish async, shouldn't several of these complete regardless of the timeout? It seems they only run if the entire function completes.

I have run a test where I cut the data down to 15k rows, and it runs without any issue, in roughly 15 seconds.

So the question, why are the async calls not firing prior to the function timeout, and any input on how I can optimize this without moving away from Lambda?

Lambda Config: nodeJS 10.x, 1024 mb, 90 second timeout

Comment: To be honest this is somehow complicated. But what I know is that interrupting JS execution doesn't affect any previously processed code or functions! This can get proven anytime by simulating it on regular nodejs server. So assuming this is a Lambda behavior, there are some techniques could be used to overcome this such as [Fanout](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/messaging-fanout-pattern-for-serverless-architectures-using-amazon-sns/) pattern which can be very useful here! Take a look at this [blog](https://shorturl.at/szR06) I found it well-explained.

Comment: I am essentially performing a fanout pattern here. But, in order to do this successfully I have to be able to parse the file first...

Comment: Wait a second, how is this parsing while it also publish the messages. Isn't executing ```await Promise.all(requests);``` the core issue? so fan-out means spreading it to multiple executions? and thus we can contain the timeout limit and the RAM restrictions? I guess I'm missing something here!